# Change specific column order without using columns names in a Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My DF has the following columns:

```
df.columns = ['not-changing1', 'not-changing2', 'changing1', 'changing2', 'changing3', 'changing4']
```

I want to swap the last 4 columns WITHOUT USING COLUMNS NAMES, but using their index instead.

So, the final column order would be:

```
result.columns = ['not-changing1', 'not-changing2', 'changing1', 'changing3', 'changing2', 'changing4']
```

How do I do that?

Comment: i dont think there is any difference between the codes u shared

Comment: use `df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,4,3,5]]`